# how to validate and submit the data using knockout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I need to Validate and Submit the data using Knockout js but i am getting error for below code is: isValid is not defined and some times i am getting ViewModel is not defined

### Model Class

```
public class EnrollmentRegister
{

    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string OwnerLastName { get; set; }
    public string OwnerFirstName { get; set; }
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
}
```

### Controller :

```
      #region GetIRFEnroll
    public string GetIRFEnroll()
    {
        EnrollmentRegister oresult = new EnrollmentRegister();
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oresult);
    }
    #endregion
    [HttpPost]
    public string PostIRFEnroll(EnrollmentRegister oresult)
    {
        return "Data Recievied";
    }
```

### script file

```
               <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript">  
               </script>

        <script src="../../Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="../../Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js" type="text/javascript">
      </script>
     <script src="../../Scripts/knockout.validation.min.js" type="text/javascript">       
    </script>
  <script src="../../Scripts/Validation.Knockout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ancSubmit").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/GetIRFEnroll',
            datatype: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            async: true,
            success: function (result) {

                ViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(result);

                ViewModel.Type.extend({ required: true });
                ViewModel.BusinessName.extend({ required: true });
                ViewModel.OwnerLastName.extend({ required: true });
                ViewModel.OwnerFirstName.extend({ required: true });
                ViewModel.AccountNumber.extend({ required: true });
                ViewModel.LastName.extend({ required: true });
                ViewModel.FirstName.extend({ required: true });
                ViewModel.Email.extend({ required: true, email: true });
                ViewModel.Phone.extend({ required: true });
                ViewModel.Zip.extend({ required: true });
                ViewModel.City.extend({ required: true });
                ViewModel.State.extend({ required: true });
                ViewModel.Address.extend({ required: true });
                ViewModel.errors = validationSet([ViewModel.BusinessName,  
    ViewModel.OwnerLastName, ViewModel.OwnerFirstName, ViewModel.AccountNumber, 
    ViewModel.LastName, ViewModel.FirstName, ViewModel.Email, ViewModel.Phone, 
    ViewModel.Zip, ViewModel.City, ViewModel.State, ViewModel.Address]);
                ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
                if (ViewModel.errors().length > 0) {
                  var  isValid = false;
                    $('.Validations').css('display', 'block');
                }
                else 
                   isValid = true;

            }

        });
        if (isValid) {

            $.ajax({
                url: '/user/PostIRFEnroll',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: ko.toJSON(ViewModel),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

                }
            });
        }
        ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
    });
  });
  </script>
```

### cshtml :

```
      <table>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="color: Red;">
        * All fields are required
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Enrollment Date
    </td>
    <td>
        <span id="currentDate"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Type
    </td>
    <td>
        <select id="ddlType" data-bind="value:Type">
            <option value="select">Select</option>
            <option value="Body">Body</option>
            <option value="Mechanical">Mechanical</option>
            <option value="Both">Both</option>
        </select>
        <span class="Validations" style="color: Red; display: none;" data-   
   bind="validator:Type">
            Required</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Business Name
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="BusinessName" type="text" style="width: 250px;" data-bind="value: 
  BusinessName"
            placeholder="Enter Business Name" />
        <span class="Validations" style="color: Red; display: none;" data-
bind="validator: BusinessName" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Owner First Name
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="OwnerFirstName" type="text" style="width: 250px;" data-bind="value: 
  OwnerFirstName"
            placeholder="Enter Owner First Name" />
        <span class="Validations" style="color: Red; display: none;" data-  
  bind="validator: OwnerFirstName" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Owner Last Name
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="OwnerLastName" type="text" style="width: 250px;" data-bind="value: 
 OwnerLastName"
            placeholder="Enter Owner Last Name" />
        <span class="Validations" style="color: Red; display: none;" data-
 bind="validator: OwnerLastName" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width: 20%">
        Billing Contact ID
        <br />
        (from DMS)
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="AccountNumber" type="text" style="width: 250px;" data-bind="value:    
 AccountNumber"
            placeholder="Enter AccountNumber" />
        <span class="Validations" style="color: Red; display: none;" data- 
  bind="validator: AccountNumber" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Contact First Name
        <br>
        <span style="font-size: 10px;">(Rewards assigned to this person)</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="FirstName" type="text" style="width: 250px;" data-bind="value:   
 FirstName"
            placeholder="Enter First Name" />
        <span class="Validations" style="color: Red; display: none;" data-
 bind="validator: FirstName" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Contact Last Name<br>
        <span style="font-size: 10px;">(Rewards assigned to this person)</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="LastName" type="text" style="width: 250px;" data-bind="value: 
  LastName"
            placeholder="Enter Last Name" />
        <span class="Validations" style="color: Red; display: none;" data-bind="validator: LastName" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Email Address
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="Email" type="text" style="width: 250px;" data-bind="value: Email" 
  placeholder="Enter Email Address" />
        <span class="Validations" style="color: Red; display: none;" data-
 bind="validator: Email" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Confirm Email Address
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="ConfirmEmail" type="text" style="width: 250px;" placeholder="Enter 
  Confirm Email Address"
            />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="msgconfrmemail" style="display: none;">
    <td colspan="2">
        <label style="color: Red;">
            Email Address and Confirm Email Address do not match.</label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Business Phone Number
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="Phone" type="text" style="width: 250px;" data-bind="value: Phone" 
  placeholder="Enter Phone Number" />
        <span class="Validations" style="color: Red; display: none;" data-
  bind="validator: Phone" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        Address
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="Address" type="text" style="width: 250px;" data-bind="value: Address"
            placeholder="Enter Address" />
        <span class="Validations" style="color: Red; display: none;" data-
 bind="validator: Address" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        City
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="City" type="text" style="width: 250px;" data-bind="value: City" 
placeholder="Enter City" />
        <span class="Validations" style="color: Red; display: none;" data-
bind="validator: City" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        State
    </td>
    <td>
        <select id="ddlState" data-bind="value:State">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="New York">New York</option>
            <option value="Latin"> Latin</option>
            <option value="">NA</option>
        </select>
        <span class="Validations" data-bind="validator: State" style="color: Red; 
 display: none;">
            Required</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Zip
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="Zip" type="text" style="width: 250px;" data-bind="value: Zip"  
 placeholder="Enter Zip" />
        <span class="Validations" style="color: Red; display: none;" data-
 bind="validator: Zip" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td>
        <div style="float: left; margin-bottom: 7px; margin-left: 0px">
            <input type="button" id="ancSubmit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
        <div style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; height: 39px; padding-
 top: 12px">
            <a href="/" style="color: #3F48DD; text-decoration: underline; cursor:     
  pointer; padding-left: 33px;">
                Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Just an advice. You generally get higher quality feedback if you provide a JSFiddle for Javascript related questions.

Comment: code contains not only javascript but mvc action methods..that's why i am not able to give in Jsfiddle

Comment: isValid is defined in a place, and checked in another scope. Plus, your code implies you are using synchronous ajax call, which is not the case. You should move the `if(isValid)` part in the `success` function